# Recyclerview addOnItemTouchListener get whichsubview is clicked inside row

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

I've implemented Recyclerview onclickListener from  this  [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick/26196831#26196831) solution. This solution works fine for the recycler item clicks. But I can't able to get which subview(ex: ImageView,Button) is clicked from the row.

```
     mAttachmentRecyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    if (view.getId()==R.id.attachmnet_remove) {
                        attachmentsList.remove(position);
                        mAttachmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        attachmentCount--;
                    }
                }
            }
    ));
```

`onItemClick(view,position)` always returns view **id** as **-1**

How do I track whick view is clicked??

Answer (score 8):

Below is a `ViewHolder` that contains two text views viz. `title` and `description`:

```
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final OnViewClickListener mListener;
    public final TextView title;
    public final TextView description;

    public interface OnViewClickListener {
        void onViewClick(View v, int adapterPosition);
    }

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView, OnViewClickListener mListener) {
        super(itemView);
        this.mListener = mListener;
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);

        title.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        description.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    }

    private final View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mListener.onViewClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    };
}
```

Both of these subviews have an `OnClickListener` attached to them that calls the custom `OnViewClickListener` implementation passing the `View` that was clicked as well as the **position of the** `RecyclerView` **item in the adapter** that received the click event.

Finally use `View.getId()` to retrieve the clicked view's id in `OnViewClickListener` implementation.

Answer (score 5):

That answer is outdated in that it uses `RecyclerView.getChildPosition(View)` which is *deprecated*. Try replacing it with `RecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(View)`.

If I was you, I would just create listeners for every `ViewHolder` and its child views that you want to listen to. Honestly, I don't seem to see the benefit of using that more complicated method that you referenced. Also, that method will only tell you that an item was clicked, nothing about the item's child views.

In addition, according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html), `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` is meant to be used when you want to detect a touch to an item while the list is scrolling, not for regular or direct touches.

Comment: Totally agree with your comment for  create listeners for every ViewHolder

Answer (score 1):

**Set Tags**

You can set Tag to your views while initializing them via:

```
view1.setTag(1);
```

This will set the view Tag to 1.

then In onItemClick method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
 if(view.getTag()==1)
 {
 //do something
 }
 else
 {
 //do something else
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add onClickListeners to the subviews.